# How to drop this custom type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL, working on a databases project. I have two custom types, `changedat` and `changedby` defined by the following code:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[changedat] FROM [smalldatetime] NULL
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[changedby] FROM [nvarchar](30) NULL
GO
```

I'm working on my rollback script and not sure how to drop these types. They don't show up in `sys.objects`.

Comment: They **do** show up in `select * from sys.types`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TYPE dbo.changedat;
DROP TYPE dbo.changedby;
GO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [sql-server doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174407.aspx) there you can see that you have ro use

```
DROP TYPE [ schema_name. ] type_name [ ; ]
```